# PyQt4 QWizard: How to disable the back button on a single page?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I would like to disable the "Back" button on a QWizard page.

My Class inherits from QWizard and from a generated file. It looks somehow like this:

from PyQt4 import QtGui

```
class WizardClass(QtGui.QWizard, file.Ui_Wizard):

    def __init__(self, model):
        # Call super constructors
        QtGui.QWizard.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.model = model
```

Here http://doc.qt.digia.com/3.3/qwizard.html#backButton I found the method `setBackEnabled()`.

With `self.setBackEnabled(page1, False)` I am not able to call this method. It says:

```
"AttributeError: 'WizardClass' object has no attribute 'setBackEnabled'"
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Or is this method not available in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example that seems to work:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Wiz(QtGui.QWizard):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWizard.__init__(self)
        self.noback = []
        self.currentIdChanged.connect(self.disable_back)

    def disable_back(self, ind):
        if ind in self.noback:
            self.button(QtGui.QWizard.BackButton).setEnabled(False)

wiz = Wiz()
wiz.noback = [2]
wiz1 = QtGui.QWizardPage(wiz)
wiz2 = QtGui.QWizardPage(wiz)
wiz3 = QtGui.QWizardPage(wiz)

wiz.addPage(wiz1)
wiz.addPage(wiz2)
wiz.addPage(wiz3)

wiz.show()
```

Comment: The statement `self.button(QWizard.BackButton).setEnabled(False)` has no effect on my wizard. (Seams like an empty method to me!?) Is it possible to specify the page somewhere? The "back" button should be disabled only on a specific page.

Comment: Oh! It worked for me. If you only want it to apply to one page (I hadn't realised this), then it should be called in that page's QtWizardPage.initializePage(), and re-enabled in .cleanupPage(). If its only the last page, you can specifically set the options: http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtwizard/qtwizard.html#WizardOption-enum

Comment: `.setEnabled(False)`  works for me for the common push buttons but not for the wizard buttons like back and next. However reimplementing `.initializePage()` was a good idea.

Comment: Please share what finally worked, in either a new answer or an edit to mine.

Comment: The problem is still not solved.
From my point of view there are two different kinds of buttons (in a QWizard!):
1: Buttons I implemented myself
2: Buttons implemented by Qt (like "Back" and "Next" on each page or "Finish" at the last page)
For the first kind of buttons your solution `Button.setEnabled(False)` worked.
But the question was to disable the "Back" button (implemented by Qt) on a single page. I am still looking for a way to do this. I am using PyQt4 and Qt Designer. Maybe one of these two are causing the problem.

Comment: I edited my answer to an example that I think does what you are after.